# $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{a-i \infty}^{a+ i \infty} e^{st} \hat{f}(s) ds = \frac{2 e^{at}}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Re(\hat{f}(a+iu)) \cos ut du$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

The claim is from this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220668741_Numerical_Inversion_of_Laplace_Transforms_of_Probability_Distributions. The whole thing goes as:

[image]

And where $\hat{f}$ is the Laplace transfrom of $f$.

But I dont get the last line. Where does that come from? Function $f$ is assumed to be real, so I understand how imaginary parts cancel each other away, but the last line seem to assume $\Re(\hat{f}(a+iu))\cos ut = -\Im(\hat{f}(a+iu))\sin ut$ (!?), which kind of result I have never heard of and could not find from the references.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I actually think that it's not more than plugging in the definition of the Laplace transform. Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't see how that would help. However, I can easily get to the second last line by opening up the $\hat{f}(a+iu)$ to its imaginary and real parts.

Comment: That is what I thought, but then there would be exp(at)/pi, not 2*exp(at)/pi, in front of the integral, right? And doesn't the sine make the imaginary part even.

Comment: After all, it's probably more complicated than expected. Nonetheless, here is the same result in another paper (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82824647.pdf) and I think it's probably related to the choice of $a$ having no singularities to the right. I unfortunately cannot help you further at the moment, might look further into it later :/

Comment: That Doetsch could have an explanation, but the book is bloody expensive.

Comment: I have access to the book and checked the pages but it’s not written explicitly. If you want to have a look give me your email and i can send it to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97117/discussion-between-mundo-and-b00n-het).

Comment: Could it possibly follow from some kind of monotone class arguments (for e.g. integrable functions?). What I noticed, it is somewhat easy to show that for a rectangle function
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
1,  0 \leq t \leq 1\\
0, \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
indeed $\int \Re\hat{f}(a+iu)\cos(ut) du = - \int \Im \hat{f}(a+iu)\sin(ut) du.$ This can be concluded by plugging in the definition of Laplace transform and by straight calculating the integrals.

 Properties of $f$ seems to play crucial role here.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is  real valued and $a,u$ are real then $\hat{f}(a+iu)  = \overline{\hat{f}(a-iu)}$ so that (assuming the Fourier inversion theorem)

$$e^{-at} f(t) = \frac{e^{-at}}{2 \pi i} \int_{a-i \infty}^{a+ i \infty} e^{st} \hat{f}(s) ds = \frac{1}{2\pi}\Re( \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \hat{f}(a+iu))e^{iut}dt)\\= \frac{ 1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Re(\hat{f}(a+iu)) \cos ut \ dt- \frac{ 1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Im(\hat{f}(a+iu)) \sin ut \ du$$
one term is even and the other one is odd so it must be 
$$ =  \frac{e^{-at} f(t)+e^{at} f(-t)}{2} \quad -\quad\frac{e^{at} f(-t)-e^{-at} f(t)}{2}$$
whence for $t > 0$, if also $f$ vanishes on $t < 0$  it is
$$f(t) = 2  \frac{e^{-at} f(t)+e^{at} f(-t)}{2}  = \frac{ 2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Re(\hat{f}(a+iu)) \cos ut \ dt$$

Comment: Why 
$$
\frac{e^{-at}f(t) + e^{at}f(-t)}{2}= (1/\pi) \int_0^{\infty} \Re(\hat{f}(a+iu))\cos ut dt?
$$

Comment: Because $e^{-at}f(t)$ is the sum of an even and odd function in a unique way

Comment: Can you please provide a reference? Thanks. I understand that every function is a sum of even and odd functions, yeah.

Comment: A reference for what ? For any function $F(t)=  \frac12 (F(t)+F(-t)) +  \frac12 (F(t)-F(-t))$ and this is the only one decomposition into even + odd

Comment: Well I meant reference for that uniqueness. But I already found one proof for that.

Answer (score -1):

The result follows from monotone class theorem for functions [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem). Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a set of functions $f$ which admits the condition
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Re \hat{f}(a+ui) \cos(ut) du = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Im \hat{f}(a+ui) \sin(ut) du,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a \xi} \sin (u \xi) \cos(ut)f(\xi) d \xi  du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a \xi} \sin(u \xi)  \sin(ut)f(\xi) d\xi du.
$$
Assuming $a>0$ one can verify the following cases:

(1) If $A \subset \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{0\},$ then by evaluating the integrals one can conclude that $ f(x) = \mathbb{1}(x \in A) \in \mathcal{H}.$

(2) If $g,f \in \mathcal{H},$ then by linearity $g+f, cf \in \mathcal{H}$ for $ c \in \mathbb{R}.$

(3) If $f_n \in \mathcal{H}$ is a sequence of non-negative functions that increase to a bounded function $f,$ then by monotone convergence theorem $f \in \mathcal{H}.$

Consequently all bounded integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{0\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{H}.$

Comment: Why downvote? Is there something wrong with this?